# How do I solve this error encountered when parsing lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, parsing, pdb

I've encountered an error with parsing lists in Python that I do not understand.

What I'm doing:

- I'm trying to optimize a function using the differential evolution method from scipy.optimize.
- The Diff EV method passes in a set of parameters (which I call "params" in my code) to the optimizable function in the form of a numpy array.
- I try to parse this array into the constituent parameters using the following line:
  `a, b, peak_temp, start_time = params`

However, the model fails when attempting to run the optimizable function. Using the debugger, I see that the params passed in look correct (I've converted them from np array to python list). the output for a in the terminal looks the same as params, there is no output for b, and start_time and peak_temp are both correct.
[image: looking at variables]

However, if I print each parameter, the correct values are displayed.

[image: printing variables]

But if I try to perform an operation on the variable, it fails for b, it shows the params for a, and it performs the correct operation for start_time and peak_temp
[image: performing operations on variables]

This seems like a simple problem, I have not previously encountered anything like this before. I cannot find anything like this online and I am desperate to fix the problem, since I'm now unable to optimize my model like I wanted to.

Comment: This isn't really a parsing issue, but a misunderstanding on how pdb is interpreting your input commands. I think this is still a worthwhile question, but consider retitling the question.

Answer (score 1):

pdb takes a little getting used to - in some ways it feels like the interactive '>>>' REPL, but it is *not* the same.

The most notable difference is that pdb is first a debugger, and every line you enter is first parsed as a debugging command - if the line does not match a debugging command, then pdb tries to evaluate it as a local variable. That's why you can type "start_time" and get the value for the `start_time` variable, because there is not pdb command "start_time".

Single character variables can be especially annoying to work with in pdb, because so many pdb commands have single character abbreviations. Like "p" for "print", "n" for "next", "s" for "step", "c" for "continue",... aaaaand "b" for "break"!

To work around this, start the line with "!", indicating that you plan to enter an actual Python statement. If you had typed "!b", then the value for `b` should display. For `b*3`, you would do "!b*3".

Here is a link to the pdb debugging commands: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html?debugger-commands